# What can I use a Feat of Strength for?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I heard that Diablo 3 closed beta players will be getting a Feat of Strength called "One of the Chosen" and a sigil that they can display on their banner.

I understand the sigil part, but I couldn't gather what exactly the Feat of Strength was. What does it do and can I use it for something useful?

Comment: What can you use any achievement for?

Comment: @NickT I had no idea "Feat of Strength" just stood for achievement.

Comment: Feat of Strength is a specific kind of achievement, much like "Poodle" is a specific kind of Dog.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Feats of Strength show up in other Blizzard Battle.net 2.0 games. Both Starcraft 2 and World of Warcraft Feature them.

Blizzard achievements are worth a certain number of points, which is displayed on your relevant battle.net profile, but Feats of Strength always are worth 0 points.

Feats of Strength are also not listed anywhere on the achievement list - it's not that they're hidden, but rather that the majority of them are one-time or limited-time events, and it is *impossible* to achieve them. (For instance, "Log on during WoW's 7th anniversary").

What this means, is that Blizzard has a way to acknowledge or commemorate players at certain times and events without affecting the number of earnable achievement points.

But don't take my word for it, this is straight from Blizzard CM Bashiok:

> The distinction between a Feat of Strength and an Achievement is that
>   an Achievement is something you can work to achieve, and a Feat of
>   Strength is either limited due to an outside factor, or is just simply
>   impossible to get any longer.
>
> Things like attending BlizzCon, where only a few thousand people can
>   attend, is a Feat of Strength.
>
> Of course there are plenty of people who want each of the Feats of
>   Strength, but the reason why they aren't Achievements, and don't
>   provide Achievement points, is due to the limited-time, invite only,
>   or simply impossible nature of obtaining them.

[Original Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4887759373?page=8#144)

Comment: Note that not all Feats of Strength are impossible to earn, and some do give some benefits, e.g. [Insane in the Membrane](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=2336) is as far as I know still obtainable and it gives you a title.

Comment: I was doing Insane in the Membrane FoS, but ... if i have finished it, I was single today... =X

Comment: From WoW: Old achievements that are no longer achievable, or hard achievements that have become trivial due to a new expansion, usually are converted to a FoS. E.g. obtaining the key to the top-end raid will start out as an achievement, but usually at some point everyone will be given access. At that point, the achievement will be turned into a FoS so you can still show off that once you were hardcore enough to earn it.

Answer (score 1):

Feats of Strength do nothing.  They are similar to achievements, but are tracked separately to indicate that they are distinct from achievements, and do not contribute to achievement totals.